# Modification of file names

Tags: linux, file, file-rename

I have a list of more than 1000 files on the following format.

```
0521865417_roman_pottery_in_the_archaeological_record_2007.pdf
0521865476_power_politics_and_religion_in_timurid_iran_2007.pdf
0521865514_toward_a_theory_of_human_rights_religion_law_courts_2006.pdf
0521865522_i_was_wrong_the_meanings_of_apologies_2008.pdf
```

I am on Linux and want to change them as follows

```
2007_roman_pottery_in_the_archaeological_record.pdf
2007_power_politics_and_religion_in_timurid_iran.pdf
2006_toward_a_theory_of_human_rights_religion_law_courts.pdf
2008_i_was_wrong_the_meanings_of_apologies.pdf
```

Using rename and awk I managed to get

```
2007_roman_pottery_in_the_archaeological_record_2007.pdf
2007_power_politics_and_religion_in_timurid_iran_2007.pdf
2006_toward_a_theory_of_human_rights_religion_law_courts_2006.pdf
2008_i_was_wrong_the_meanings_of_apologies_2008.pdf
```

The remaining task is now to remove the last field that holds the year.

Comment: Use the `rename` command, which allows you to use Perl-style substitution  expressions to specify how the filename gets renamed.

Comment: This may be better suited to another SE site, like SuperUser.

Comment: You should be able to find examples of how to do this on superuser.com and unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You can perform this operation in almost any popular programming/scripting language (Java, Python, Perl, Bash, etc.). As @Barmar noted, there are also a plethora of commandline utilities that perform this operation.

Comment: This is clearly a job for `mmv`.

Comment: I am trying to use rename

Comment: The following will remove the first field `rename 's/[^_]*_//' *.pdf`

Comment: Any command for doing the last part? Cannot think of anything that might work.

Comment: can you post your awk command that you used to get the latest result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that uses `sed` to generate the new names and the rename commands then pipes them to `bash`:

```
ls -1 | sed -r 's/[0-9]*_([A-Za-z_]*)_[a-z]{3}_([0-9]{4})\.pdf$/mv & \2_\1.pdf/g' | bash
```

Comment: Have tried with file `2007_test_2007.pdf` and it does not seem to work

Comment: The file names you posted in the question end with `_mon_year.pdf`. Do you need the `_mon` part to be optional?

Comment: apologies, I have removed the month alraedy.

Comment: If the names do not contain the month any more then remove the `_[a-z]{3}` part from the command and use the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

A work around from where you left of...

```
echo 2007_roman_pottery_in_the_archaeological_record_2007.pdf | awk -F '_' '{$NF=""; OFS="_"; print substr($0, 0, length($0)-1)".pdf";}'
```